# Counting in sentence

Tags: fortran, counting, sentence

I'm trying to write a code to get the following format

filein(i)='box_01_step_000000000000j.pdb'

the output should be like:

```
filein(1)='box_01_step_00000000000000.pdb' 
filein(2)='box_01_step_00000000000020.pdb'
filein(3)='box_01_step_00000000000040.pdb'
filein(4)='box_01_step_00000000000060.pdb'
filein(5)='box_01_step_00000000000080.pdb'
filein(6)='box_01_step_00000000000100.pdb'
filein(7)='box_01_step_00000000000120.pdb'
filein(8)='box_01_step_00000000000140.pdb'
filein(9)='box_01_step_00000000000160.pdb'
filein(10)='box_01_step_00000000000180.pdb'
filein(11)='box_01_step_00000000000200.pdb'
```

My code is

```
program main 
implicit none 
 integer :: i,n,j
 character(4):: filein,box,step,pdb
 do i = 0, 501
    open (300,file='in')
 end do
 j=0
 do i = 0, 501   
  j=j+20
  WRITE(300,*) "'filein'",'"("',(i),'")"',"'='","'box_01_step_'","'000000000000'",j,"'.pdb'"
 enddo
 close (300)
end program
```

I got

```
 'filein'"("           0 ")"'=''box_01_step_''000000000000'          20 '.pdb'
 'filein'"("           1 ")"'=''box_01_step_''000000000000'          40 '.pdb'
 'filein'"("           2 ")"'=''box_01_step_''000000000000'          60 '.pdb'
 'filein'"("           3 ")"'=''box_01_step_''000000000000'          80 '.pdb'
```

How I can make it

```
filein(1)='box_01_step_00000000000000.pdb' 
filein(2)='box_01_step_00000000000020.pdb'
filein(3)='box_01_step_00000000000040.pdb'
```

Answer (score 1):

- to start the i values from 1 instead of 0, use a starting value of 1 instead of 0
- to start the j values from 0 instead of 20, do the add *after* the output instead of before -- or instead of using a separate variable j just compute it from i
- don't open the file 502 times; once is enough
- to convert j to decimal with leading zeros the simplest way by far is to use formatted output with the `Iw.m` specifier, and formatted output is also a somewhat easier way of doing the rest of what you want

Program:

```
program SO44379759
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  open(300,file='in')
  ! j=0
  do i=1,501
    ! j=j+20
    write(300,'(a,i0,a,i14.14,a)') "filein(",i,")='box_01_step_",(i-1)*20,".pdb'"
  end do
  close(300)
end program
```

Output:

```
filein(1)='box_01_step_00000000000000.pdb'
filein(2)='box_01_step_00000000000020.pdb'
filein(3)='box_01_step_00000000000040.pdb'
filein(4)='box_01_step_00000000000060.pdb'
filein(5)='box_01_step_00000000000080.pdb'
filein(6)='box_01_step_00000000000100.pdb'
filein(7)='box_01_step_00000000000120.pdb'
filein(8)='box_01_step_00000000000140.pdb'
filein(9)='box_01_step_00000000000160.pdb'
filein(10)='box_01_step_00000000000180.pdb'
filein(11)='box_01_step_00000000000200.pdb'
filein(12)='box_01_step_00000000000220.pdb'
filein(13)='box_01_step_00000000000240.pdb'
filein(14)='box_01_step_00000000000260.pdb'
filein(15)='box_01_step_00000000000280.pdb'
filein(16)='box_01_step_00000000000300.pdb'
filein(17)='box_01_step_00000000000320.pdb'
filein(18)='box_01_step_00000000000340.pdb'
filein(19)='box_01_step_00000000000360.pdb'
filein(20)='box_01_step_00000000000380.pdb'
```